# how to add pin locations in google maps in android according to several longitudes and latitudes

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, latitude-longitude, android-maps

this is my map activity and i need to put several pin locations on this map according to my own coordinates returned from my own database from another server.

public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {

```
MapView map;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    map = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mvMain);
    map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    MapController myMapController = map.getController();
    myMapController.setCenter(new GeoPoint((int)(7.5653 * 1E6),(int)(80.4303 * 1E6)));
    myMapController.setZoom(8);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make a good search before u ask.

but here an sample for similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482650/google-maps-android-set-too-many-markers)

[previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295203/adding-multiple-marker-on-google-map-in-android)

and here [Good tutorial](http://myandroidsolutions.blogspot.com/2012/03/android-how-to-put-markerspins-on-map.html)